# Protect Oracle database against SQL Injection

Tags: php, sql, oracle, symfony4, sql-injection

I'm on Symfony and I don't know how protect my database against sql injection. If you have some idea, I will be gratefull.

My function with sql :

```
  public function getResult($$value)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT SOMETHING FROM SOMETHING smt
                WHERE smt.THING = '".$value."'";

        return $this->egee->executeQuery($sql);

    }
```

And here is my executeQuery funciton :

```
   public function executeQuery($sql) {

        $entityManager = $this->em->getConnection('xxx');

        $stmt = $entityManager->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute();

       return $stmt->fetch();
    }
```

I allready try with BindParam, but it's didn't work with Oracle.
With BindParam I have this response :

Error 503 : Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Comment: *"it's didn't work with Oracle"* - what exactly happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it ... with any and every database: ***parameterized queries.***

Your SQL string now becomes:

```
SELECT SOMETHING FROM SOMETHING smt WHERE smt.THING = ?
```

Notice the `?` *(which is not in quotes ... this is not a one-character literal string)*  This indicates a query parameter.

Now, each time you execute the query, you supply an `array()` containing each of the parameter-values you want to substitute, in order left-to-right.  Different values may be used each time the query is executed *(without re-preparing it)*, because these values are not "part of" the query:  they are *inputs.*

No matter what the parameter-value contains, the database engine will never see it as anything other than the numeric or string *value* that it is.  It will never regard it as "part of the SQL."  Thus, SQL-injection becomes impossible.

Furthermore, the [binary] value is used directly, instead of being decoded from a character string.  So, say, if you want to use quote-marks as part of your string parameter-value, you *would not* "encode" them with backslashes.  (If you provided `\"`, then "a backslash followed by a quote mark" is what SQL would see as the parameter's value ... a perfectly acceptable *two-character* value.)

Here's a nice write-up:  https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work but I have this response : 
Error 503 : Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Doctrine ORM in the Symfony manual shows an example of using a query parameter:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-with-sql

```
$sql = '
    SELECT * FROM product p
    WHERE p.price > :price
    ORDER BY p.price ASC
    ';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['price' => $price]);
```

You don't need to use BindParam. Just pass a hash array to `execute()`, where the hash keys are the named query parameter placeholders you put in your SQL query.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work too but I have the same response : 
Error 503 : Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Comment: That's a general http status code, it's not necessarily caused by the database query. You need to examine the http server error logs to get more information about the cause. It could be caused by a large variety of PHP errors.